Which one sounds more like a suggestion of a possible option for consideration?
Which one of the following sentences sounds more like a suggestion of a possible action for consideration and which one sounds like the gaining of a future ability?

If the enemy retreats, we can ambush them on their way.

If the enemy retreats, we’ll be able to ambush them on their way.



related: "be able to" "can"

Also possible are could or should; it depends on situation and tone/emphasis, if you're giving an order, offering a suggestion at the time, or giving a suggestion from the point of view of someone not directly involved.

@StuartF Should I use “can” or “will be able to” to give an offer or a suggestion?

If the enemy retreats, we can [suggestion of possible action] ambush them on their way.
If the enemy retreats, we’ll be able to [gain the ability to] ambush them on their way.

In practice, I think this is just a literal distinction that makes no difference to the actual meaning. And the question is the problem, since it erroneously assumes those two literal rephrasings actually make a difference. In nearly every context, they're semantically equivalent. There might be more of a difference if we replaced we can by we might.

+1  "can" is used to suggest a possible course of action. "We can watch a movie or listen to some music."  Not that "we will be able to" can't have that meaning too, in context, but why use four words when you can use one?  "can" is optimal.

Thanks for replying. Are you a native speaker of English?  @Peter Jennings

@TimR “will be able to” might have that similar meaning too, but not as strong or common as “can”

@ChienTeLu  Are you asking me or telling me?

@TimR asking you if you agree with me.

@ChienTeLu  Certainly not as common.  I think the strength is probably the same -- it would depend on the prosody. Emphasis on ambush would  focus attention of the course of action in both versions.

@TimR I think given the same context, "can" sounds more like a suggestion.
e.g.
Example 1
A: What should we do next?
B: If it stops raining, we can play basketball in the park. (Playing basketball is an available action I suggest for consideration given the weather getting better)
Example 2
A: What should we do next?
B: If it stops raining, we'll be able to play basketball in the park. (We will gain the ability to play basket ball if the weather gets better)
Do you agree with my comparison?

can is often used to  make a suggestion whereas "we'll be able to X" is used in such contexts often when the suggestion has already been made but there's some present obstacle to acting upon the suggestion, like rain.  However, we'll be able can also be used to make the suggestion, albeit less forcefully, by "floating" it as a possibility:  What shall we do this afternoon? --If it stops raining, we'll be able to play basketball.  Maybe floating a possibility doesn't rise to the level of "suggestion" -- but that's a fine line.

@TimR I think yes it can sound like a possibility albeit less direct. I think the gaining of ability concept is still stronger with "will be able to". Do you think "can" is more direct when suggesting a possible action?
